# Using requests_oauthlib to access OAuth2 web page

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0, python-requests

Have been following a tutorial about using `Requests` and `BeautifulSoup4` for web scraping. I am trying to access info from `www.showmyhomework.com` website but I believe the site is using `OAuth2` authorisation. Unfortunately the tutorial does not cover how to do this with pages with `OAuth2`. Have spent hours reading the `OAuth2` documentation but can't figure out how I get my Python script to request a token and get access to the web page. The python script below is from the `OAuth2` documentation but I am clearly doing something wrong!

```
from oauthlib.oauth2 import LegacyApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

client_Id = 'My_Google_supplied_OAuth2_Client_Id.apps.googleusercontent.com'
client_Secret = 'My_Google_supplied OAuth Client_Secret'
redirect_uri = 'https://your.callback/uri'

oauth = OAuth2Session(client=LegacyApplicationClient(client_id=client_Id))
token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url='https://www.showmyhomework.com/oauth2/token',
            username="My_Username", password="My_Password", client_id=client_Id,
            client_secret=client_Secret)
print(token)
```

I get these errors in response:

```
=================== RESTART: E:/Programs/Python27/Auth.py ===================

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Programs/Python27/Auth.py", line 11, in <module>
    client_secret=client_Secret)
  File "E:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth2_session.py", line 244, in fetch_token
    self._client.parse_request_body_response(r.text, scope=self.scope)
  File "E:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\clients\base.py", line 409, in parse_request_body_response
    self.token = parse_token_response(body, scope=scope)
  File "E:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\parameters.py", line 376, in parse_token_response
    validate_token_parameters(params)
  File "E:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\parameters.py", line 386, in validate_token_parameters
    raise MissingTokenError(description="Missing access token parameter.")
MissingTokenError: (missing_token) Missing access token parameter.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue and I resolved it by adding `auth=False` in `fetch_token`.

```
 oauth = OAuth2Session(client=LegacyApplicationClient(client_id=client_Id))
 token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url='https://www.showmyhomework.com/oauth2/token',
        username="My_Username", password="My_Password", client_id=client_Id,
        client_secret=client_Secret, auth=False)
```

Good luck.

Comment: Why do we need to set this flag to begin with?